# How do I make my Rock-Paper-Scissor program more JavaScript-like?

Tags: javascript, game, rock-paper-scissors

I have implemented my first program in JavaScript, [Rock-Paper-Scissors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors). I would like JavaScript developers to help me make this program more JavaScript-like by following the idioms of the language. I am also open to any suggestions related to simplification of logic and code readability.

The following is the complete listing of the program:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        var choiceArray = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"];

        var getUserChoice = function()
        {
            var userChoice = undefined;
            var userChoiceIndex = undefined;

            while (true)
            {
                userChoice = prompt("What do you like - paper, scissor or rock");
                userChoiceIndex = choiceArray.indexOf(userChoice);

                if (userChoiceIndex >= 0 && userChoiceIndex <= 2)
                    return userChoice;

                alert("Invalid Choice!");
            }
        }

        var getComputerChoice = function()
        {
            var computerChoiceIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            return choiceArray[computerChoiceIndex];
        }

        var decideWinner = function(userChoice, computerChoice)
        {
            if (userChoice === computerChoice)
                return "There is a tie!";

            if (userChoice === "paper")
            {
                if (computerChoice === "rock")
                {
                    return "paper wins!";
                }
                else //scissors
                {
                    return "scissors win!";
                }
            }
            if (userChoice === "rock")
            {
                if (computerChoice === "paper")
                {
                    return "paper wins!";
                }
                else //scissors
                {
                    return "rock wins!";
                }
            }
            else //scissors
            {
                if (computerChoice === "paper")
                {
                    return "scissors wins!";
                }
                else //rock
                {
                    return "rock wins!";
                }
            }
        }

        var runGame = function()
        {
            var userChoice = getUserChoice();
            var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
            var gameResult = decideWinner(userChoice, computerChoice);
            gameResult = "Computer Choice = " + computerChoice + ". " + gameResult;
            alert(gameResult);
        }

        runGame();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, there might be a few things.

The most important thing that can be changed is removing all those magic numbers: What happens when we want to play “*Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock*” instead? You'd think you would only have to update the `choiceArray` – but unfortunately the length of that array is encoded in various places.

This means that `if (userChoiceIndex >= 0 && userChoiceIndex <= 2)` should be

```
if (userChoiceIndex >= 0 && userChoiceIndex <= choiceArray.length - 1)
```

and `var computerChoiceIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` should be

```
var computerChoiceIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceArray.length);
```

Your `decideWinner` function isn't really extensible, because you encode the winning relationships as *code*, not as the *data* it actually is. I'd use an object literal that only encodes what choice wins over another, like:

```
var winningData = {
  paper:     { rock:     true },
  rock:      { scissors: true },
  scissors:  { paper:    true }
};
```

Also, I'd implement `decideWinner` as a comparator that returns one of `-1, 0, 1` depending on whether the first or the second argument won. This decouples the decision logic from UI like text.

```
function(choiceA, choiceB) {
  if (choiceA === choiceB)           return  0;
  if (winningData[choiceA][choiceB]) return -1;
  if (winningData[choiceB][choiceA]) return  1;
  console.warn("No ordering between " + choiceA + " and " + choiceB + " was found");
  return 0;
}
```

The game result is then determined as:

```
var ordering = decideWinner(userChoice, computerChoice);
var winningMessage = ordering < 0 ? "You win!" :
                     ordering > 0 ? "The computer wins!" :
                                    "It's a tie!";
var gameResult = "You chose: "          + userChoice     + ".\n" +
                 "The computer chose: " + computerChoice + ".\n" +
                 winningMessage;
```

Now when we extend the game, we just have to update the `winningData`. Notice that I display *who* wins, not *what* choice wins, as I don't think that would be tremendously interesting to a player. Also, he would have to make an association from the choice to the player, which is unnecessary mental effort.

Comment: Note, for an even balance of power, there must be an odd number of possible choices.

Comment: @luserdroog thanks, I removed the phaser from my example.

Comment: @amon, thanks for excellent tips on extensibility. I will definitely rewrite the program considering extensibility in mind. +1.